# JavaFx Linechart render data

Tags: javafx

I have problem with linechar graph.

I don't understand, why data is not rendered:

```
package diagram;

import Database.OracleConnector;
import Hlavni.FXMLCMain;
import atribute.DiagramAttribute;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;

public class FXMLCdia implements Initializable {

    strong textprivate FXMLCMain rootWindow;

    @FXML
    private LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart;
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis numberAxisx;
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis numberAxisy;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("Portfolio 1");

        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(7, 23));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(8, 14));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 15));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(10, 24));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(11, 34));

        numberAxisx = new NumberAxis();
        numberAxisy = new NumberAxis();
        lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(numberAxisx, numberAxisy);
        lineChart.getData().addAll(series1);
        System.out.println(lineChart.getData().get(0).getData());
       //result: [Data[7,23,null], Data[8,14,null], Data[9,15,null], Data[10,24,null],Data[11,34,null]]
    }

    public void setMainWindow(FXMLCMain rootWindow) {
        this.rootWindow = rootWindow;
    }
```

Fxml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.chart.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="612.0" prefWidth="1352.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="diagram.FXMLCdia">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@fxmldia.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <LineChart fx:id="LineChart" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="605.0" prefWidth="1345.0" title="Production Oee">
        <xAxis>
          <NumberAxis fx:id="numberAxisy" animated="false" autoRanging="false" label="Hour" minorTickCount="10" minorTickLength="10.0" prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="1265.0" side="BOTTOM" tickLabelGap="1.0" tickLength="15.0" tickUnit="1.0" upperBound="23.0">
               <tickLabelFont>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </tickLabelFont></NumberAxis>
        </xAxis>
        <yAxis>
          <NumberAxis fx:id="numberAxisx" animated="false" label="Percent" minorTickCount="10" minorTickLength="10.0" side="LEFT" tickLabelGap="10.0" tickLength="15.0" tickUnit="20.0">
               <tickLabelFont>
                  <Font size="15.0" />
               </tickLabelFont></NumberAxis>
        </yAxis>
      </LineChart>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the chart from the FXML file.

```
@FXML
private LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart;
```

....

Here you create a new one

```
    lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>..
```

You don't have to make a new one as it's already made in the FXML file.  The same goes for the Axis.

Comment: I found another good answer since this gets asked a lot.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29288214/2855515

Comment: Thank for help. I found some solution how do it with hide tableview.